# How does showing that all norms are strongly equivalent imply that the identity map and the norm map are continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

In the begging of my introduction to functional analysis course the
lecture started with a proof that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are
strongly equivalent.

Then the lecture said that from this we get that the maps 
$$
id:\,(\mathbb{R}^{n},||.||_1)\to(\mathbb{R}^{n},||.||)
$$
$$
||.||:\,(\mathbb{R}^{n},||.||)\to\mathbb{R}
$$

are continuous, hence 
$$
x\mapsto||x||:\,(\mathbb{R}^{n},||.||_1)\to\mathbb{R}
$$

is continuous.

I don't understand how the conclusion that $id,||.||$ are continuous
was made from assuming that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are strongly
equivalent. Can someone please add some details ?

Comment: Weren't there some indices to differentiate between two norms? It's basically a tautology if only one norm is considered.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Thanks for pointing that out, I edited accordingly

Comment: Just use the definition of what it means for two norms to be strongly equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the equivalence of norms, you get the continuity of

$$\operatorname{id} \colon (\mathbb{R}^n, \lVert \cdot \rVert_1) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \lVert \cdot \rVert),$$

since you have a constant $c > 0$ such that $\lVert x\rVert \leqslant c\cdot \lVert x\rVert_1$ for all $x$. Then you have $\lVert x-y\rVert \leqslant c\cdot \lVert x-y\rVert_1$ for all $x,y$, and that means the identity is Lipschitz-continuous. We have not yet used the equivalence, only the estimate in one direction. The estimate in the other direction, the existence of a $C > 0$ with $\lVert x\rVert_1 \leqslant C\cdot \lVert x\rVert$ for all $x$, yields the continuity of the identity in the other direction, in other words, the two norms induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

By the triangle inequality, the each norm is (Lipschitz-) continuous in the topology induced by that norm itself,

$$\bigl\lvert \lVert x \rVert - \lVert y\rVert \bigr\rvert \leqslant \lVert x-y\rVert,$$

so the fact that the norms induce the same topology guarantees that all norms are continuous in that topology.